# Allow multiple spaces after comma in ESLint

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

I have problem with ESLint configuration. I like to put comma in new line before variables, but ESLint don't accepts three spaces (only one space is correct in this case).

What should I add to my ESLint configuration file to allow situation that I can use three spaces instead of one after comma?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the `no-multi-spaces` is providing a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [the document](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-spaces#exceptions) mentions, we can specify exceptions by ESTree node types. The comma belongs to `VariableDeclaration` node.

```
"no-multi-spaces": [
    "error", 
    {"exceptions": {"VariableDeclaration": true}}
]
```